# Having trouble creating a Firebase Query requesting only objects with a field of a certain value (in Android)

Tags: android, firebase

I have Firebase data that looks like this.

[image: Picture]

I want to create a Query object in java that retrieves only Invites (those are the objects with randomly generated key's KHcYy...) which have a name = "John Smith".

Here is the code for my current attempt, which is only giving me an empty query:

```
firebase = new Firebase(ListApplication.FIREBASE_URL);
Firebase objectRef= firebase.child("ExampleParty");
Query q = objectRef.child("brother").equalTo("John Smith");
```

I tried taking a look through [this tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) on queries, but that only really had info on doing sorty and ranking based queries. I couldn't find any info on this type of task, and the [API Reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#query_equalTo) didn't really make it clear what I'm supposed to be inputting in any of these calls.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the [Firebase guide for Android developers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/). This specific part is covered in the [section on querying](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this...

```
firebase = new Firebase(ListApplication.FIREBASE_URL);
Firebase objectRef= firebase.child("ExampleParty");
Query q = objectRef.orderByChild("brother").equalTo("John Smith");
```